# Wordpress - Post Category on page

Tags: wordpress, post, categories

I have a question: In wordpress, how can I display posts in a category on a page ?. I have many categories, and in a page, I just only want posts in a category are displayed.
Thanks for your support !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative to a plugin. This is a dynamic page template. This template lets you choose which category's posts to display on the specific page. You can use this template over and over inside the same theme

Add this to your functions.php or any functions related file

```
<?php
/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *Add a post metabox with options to the admin page screen.
 *After selcting the page-pop.php template as a page template,
 *this metabox will appear in the admin page screen.
 *From here you can choose which category's posts to display
 *and how the posts will be displayed on the page
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *1. Only add meta boxes for the pop template
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action('admin_init', 'pietergoosen_add_pop_meta_box');

function pietergoosen_add_pop_meta_box(){
$post_id = isset( $_GET['post'] ) ? $_GET['post'] : 0 ;
if($post_id) { 
$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
if ($template_file == 'page-pop.php') { 
add_meta_box('pop_meta_box', __( 'Page of Posts with the same name', 'pietergoosen' ), 'pietergoosen_pop_meta_options', 'page', 'side', 'core');
} else {
$meta = get_post_meta($post_id, '_cat_id', true);
if( $meta ) {
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_cat_id', '');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_page_title', '');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_posts_title', '');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_order_by', '');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_asc', '');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_post_count', '');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_days', '');
remove_meta_box( 'pop_meta_box', 'page', 'side' );
}
}
}
add_action('save_post', 'pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta_box');
}

/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *2. Built the list to display the options in the metabox
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$order_list = array(
'none' => array( 'value' => 'none','label' => 'None' ),
'id' => array( 'value' => 'ID','label' => 'Post ID' ),
'author' => array( 'value' => 'author','label' => 'Author' ),
'title' => array( 'value' => 'title','label' => 'Post Title' ),
'date' => array( 'value' => 'date', 'label' => 'Post Date'),
'modified' => array( 'value' => 'modified','label' => 'Modified Date' ),
'parent' => array( 'value' => 'parent','label' => 'Parent Post' ),
'rand' => array( 'value' => 'rand','label' => 'Random' ),
'comment_count' => array( 'value' => 'comment_count','label' => 'Comment Count' ),
'menu_order' => array( 'value' => 'menu_order','label' => 'Menu Order' ),
);

$sort = array(
'DESC' => array( 'value' => 'DESC','label' => 'Descending' ),
'ASC' => array( 'value' => 'ASC','label' => 'Ascending' ),
); 

function pietergoosen_pop_meta_options(){

$post_id = !empty($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : 0;
if( !$post_id ) return;

$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
if ($template_file != 'page-pop.php') return;

global $order_list,$post_styles,$sort;
$categories = get_categories();

//Check if we have values
$post_meta=array();
$post_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id,false );

$cat_id = isset( $post_meta['_cat_id'] ) ? $post_meta['_cat_id'][0] : 1;
$page_title = isset( $post_meta['_page_title'] ) && $post_meta['_page_title'] ? $post_meta['_page_title'][0] : '';
$posts_title = isset( $post_meta['_posts_title'] ) && $post_meta['_posts_title'] ? $post_meta['_posts_title'][0] : '';
$order_by = isset( $post_meta['_order_by'] ) ? $post_meta['_order_by'][0] : 'date';
$asc = isset( $post_meta['_asc'] ) ? $post_meta['_asc'][0] : 'DESC';
$post_count = isset( $post_meta['_post_count'] ) ? $post_meta['_post_count'][0] : get_option('posts_per_page');
if(!$post_count || !is_numeric( $post_count )) $post_count = get_option('posts_per_page');
$days = isset( $post_meta['_days'] ) ? $post_meta['_days'][0] : '0';
if($days && !is_numeric( $days )) $days = '0';
?>

<!-- Sart the meta boxes -->
<div class="inside">
<p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Page Title', 'pietergoosen' ); ?></strong></label></p>
<input id="_posts_title" name="_posts_title" type="text" style="width: 98%;" value="<?php echo $posts_title; ?>"/>

<p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Post Title', 'pietergoosen' ); ?></strong></label></p>
<input id="_page_title" name="_page_title" type="text" style="width: 98%;" value="<?php echo $page_title; ?>"/>

<p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Category', 'pietergoosen' ); ?></strong></label></p>
<select id="_cat_id" name="_cat_id">
<?php 
//Category List
foreach ($categories as $cat) :
$selected = ( $cat->cat_ID == $cat_id ) ? ' selected = "selected" ' : '';
$option = '<option '.$selected .'value="' . $cat->cat_ID;
$option = $option .'">';
$option = $option .$cat->cat_name;
$option = $option .'</option>';
echo $option;
endforeach;
?>
</select>

<p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Sort by', 'pietergoosen' )?></strong></label></p>
<select id="_order_by" name="_order_by">
<?php 
foreach ($order_list as $output) :
$selected = ( $output['value'] == $order_by ) ? ' selected = "selected" ' : '';
$option = '<option '.$selected .'value="' . $output['value'];
$option = $option .'">';
$option = $option .$output['label'];
$option = $option .'</option>';
echo $option;
endforeach;
?>
</select>

<p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Order', 'pietergoosen' )?><strong></label></p>
<select id="_asc" name="_asc">
<?php 
foreach ($sort as $output) :
$selected = ( $output['value'] == $asc ) ? ' selected = "selected" ' : '';
$option = '<option '.$selected .'value="' . $output['value'];
$option = $option .'">';
$option = $option .$output['label'];
$option = $option .'</option>';
echo $option;
endforeach;
?>
</select>

<p><strong><label><?php _e( 'Posts per Page', 'pageofposts' ); ?><strong></label></p>
<input id="_post_count" name="_post_count" type="text" value="<?php echo $post_count; ?>" size="3" />

<p><strong><label><?php _e( 'Posts in the last days', 'pageofposts' ); ?><strong></label></p>
<input id="_days" name="_days" type="text" value="<?php echo $days; ?>" size="3" />
</div>
<!-- End page of posts meta box -->
<?php
}
function pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta_box( $post_id ){

if ( empty( $_POST ) ) {
return;
} else {
$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
if ($template_file != 'page-pop.php') return;

if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
return $post_id;
} else {
if ( $_POST['post_type'] == 'page' ) {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
  return $post_id;
} else {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
  return $post_id;
}
$meta = isset( $_POST['_cat_id'] ) ? $_POST['_cat_id'] : 1;
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_cat_id', $meta);
$meta = isset( $_POST['_page_title'] ) ? $_POST['_page_title'] : '';
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_page_title', $meta);
$meta = isset( $_POST['_posts_title'] ) ? $_POST['_posts_title'] : '';
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_posts_title', $meta);
$meta = isset( $_POST['_order_by'] ) ? $_POST['_order_by'] : 'date';
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_order_by', $meta);
$meta = isset( $_POST['_asc'] ) ? $_POST['_asc'] : 'DESC';
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_asc', $meta);
$meta = isset( $_POST['_post_count'] ) ? $_POST['_post_count'] : get_option('posts_per_page');
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_post_count', $meta);
$meta = isset( $_POST['_days'] ) ? $_POST['_days'] : 0;
pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_days', $meta);
return;
}
}
}

function pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $data) {
$post_meta = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
if( $data != '' && $post_meta != $data) {
update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $data);
} elseif ( $post_meta != '' && $data == '' ) {
delete_post_meta($post_id, $key);
}
}
?>
```

Secondly, the page template. You have to call this template `page-pop.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page of Posts
 */
get_header(); ?>

<?php
//See if we have any values
$post_meta=array();
$post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID,false );
$catid = isset( $post_meta['_cat_id'] ) ? $post_meta['_cat_id'][0] : 1;
$page_title = isset( $post_meta['_page_title'] ) ? $post_meta['_page_title'][0] : '';
$posts_title = isset( $post_meta['_posts_title'] ) ? $post_meta['_posts_title'][0] : '';
$orderby = isset( $post_meta['_order_by'] ) ? $post_meta['_order_by'][0] : 'date';
$asc = isset( $post_meta['_asc'] ) ? $post_meta['_asc'][0] : 'DESC';
$list_style =  isset( $post_meta['_list_style'] ) ? $post_meta['_list_style'][0] : 'default';
$post_count = isset( $post_meta['_post_count'] ) ? $post_meta['_post_count'][0] : get_option('posts_per_page');
if(!$post_count || !is_numeric( $post_count )) $post_count = get_option('posts_per_page');
$days = isset( $post_meta['_days'] ) ? $post_meta['_days'][0] : 0;
if($days && !is_numeric( $days )) $days = 0;
$do_not_show_stickies = ($list_style == 'default') ? 0 : 1;
?>
<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
<div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

<!-- Page Title -->
<?php if( $posts_title ) : ?>
<article id="posts-title">
<header class="entry-header">
<h2 class="entry-title"><?php echo $posts_title; ?></h2>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
</article><!-- #posts-title -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php the_post(); ?>
<?php global $post;
if( $post->post_content || $page_title ) : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php if( $page_title ) : ?>
<header class="entry-header">
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo $page_title; ?></h1>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<?php endif; ?>
<?php if( $post->post_content ) : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'pietergoosen' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<footer class="entry-meta">

</footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
<?php endif; ?>
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php 
/* Do we have any category */
global $post;

// Save posts for later use
$tmp_post = $post;

$args = array( 
'cat' => $catid,
'posts_per_page' => $post_count,
'paged' => $paged,
'orderby' => $orderby,
'order' => $asc,
'ignore_sticky_posts' => $do_not_show_stickies,
);

if( $days ) {
function pop_filter_where( $where = '') {
global $days;
$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-' .$days .' days')) . "'";
return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'pop_filter_where' );
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'pop_filter_where' );
} else {
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query( $args );
}
// Output
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :

// Start the Loop.
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();

 get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 

endwhile;

pietergoosen_pagination();

else : 

get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

endif; ?>

<?php 
// Reset the post to the page post
$post = $tmp_post; 
?>

    <?php if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
comments_template();
} ?>

</div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar( 'content' ); ?>

</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

You can now simply create a new page and choose the "page of posts" template, and publish your page. Once that is done, the Page of Posts metabox will appear. From that you can choose the category to display on that page.

Comment: Iam editing my theme. So can you tell me where to add this code or page-pop.php. Tks

Comment: It should go in your root folder of your theme, create a new file, call it page-pop.php and add the code to it from page-pop.php. Just change all the div's according to your theme

Comment: i already had my template i want to edit in my theme. How can I modify it ?

Comment: What do you want to modify.

Comment: I already had my template. I use plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-per-cat/ but it does'nt work with my template. It works fine with another template. How can I change ?

Comment: if i want to modify my template, how can i add the code ?

Comment: I think I have explained it perfectly. I cannot help you more than this. Implementing it should really not be an issue. If you cannot do it, hire someone to help you. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that will do that. http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-per-cat/

He used the plugin then set it to a ridiculous number so that it would show all the categories on the page. Here's the link to the website I found the answer on:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45856/show-posts-of-category-in-a-page

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to seperate my custom post type, is this plugin can help ?

Comment: @ZhuGheLiang yes it can. It has a whole range of features.